# Selenium doesn't run with Java 1.6

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, java-8, java-6

I have to run some tests with Selenium using Java 1.6, but I'm getting this error when I'm trying to do that:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=org/openqa/selenium/Capabilities, offset=6
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:275)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:69)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:529)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:440)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$300(URLClassLoader.java:68)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1027)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:346)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:70)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:516)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.createTest(TestSuite.java:61)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestMethod(TestSuite.java:294)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestsFromTestCase(TestSuite.java:150)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.<init>(TestSuite.java:129)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.<init>(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit3Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit3Builder.java:14)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I know that I see this error because of not compatible Java version, but is it possible to run my tests with Java 1.6? Or which Selenium version was compiled in Java 1.6? Now I'm using Selenium 2.53.1.

Comment: try to use an older selenium version

Comment: You can always run this under new versions of Java by specifying compatibility mode

Comment: Downgrade to 2.xx, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java

Comment: Java provides backward compatibility which means a code base compiled with older javac version runs fine with a newer java version but the reverse is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 2.47.0 requires java 7.  Before that was 2.46.0.

v2.47.0

** Java 7 is now requried, but you really should be on 8, since 7 is EOL **
(sic)
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG